# How to directly create a categorical series in dask?

Tags: python, dask

I would like to create a categorical dask `Series` based on a filter on another series.  With pandas, I would do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series(np.random.random(10))
test = (x < 0.5).astype(int)
label = pd.Series(pd.Categorical.from_codes(test, categories=['a', 'b']))
```

If `x` is a dask `Series`, is there a way to create an equivalent `label` dask series without having to explicitly create the pandas series first (e.g., avoiding `.compute()` and `from_pandas`)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you need is available, as follows

```
import dask.array as da
import dask.dataframe as dd

r = da.random.random(1000000, chunks=(10000,))  # dask array
s = dd.from_array(r)  # dask series
label = s.map_partitions(
    lambda d: pd.Series(pd.Categorical.from_codes(
    d < 0.5, categories=['a', 'b'])), meta='category')
```

(of course, replace your `s` with real data if you didn't really want random numbers)